# how to redraw views inside a collectionview cell after switching to a different flow layout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I got my collectionview of photos to change layout with the following code:

> newLayout = [[SDCGalleryLayout alloc] init];

and then

> [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:newLayout animated:YES];

It works fine and it animates from one layout to another.   However, the view inside my collectionviewcell is not resizing to account for its new cell size.   drawRect() of the views inside the collectionviewcell is not being called.

Any suggestions to get the views inside my collection cells to redraw after changing a layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use -(void)layoutSubviews of the UIView inside the collection view cell.  Works like a charm